# WSUS console : Unable to connect to server from wsus console

Tags: wsus

I am facing this issue from the last 1 month. The problem is when I try to open the WSUS from Administrative tools, I am able to open it but the left console tree only shows update services. When I try to connect to the server I am getting the error message as "Cannot connect to "SERVER NAME". The server may be using another port or different Secure Sockets Layer Setting. I'm using WSUS 3.0 SP2 with Windows 2003 server SP2.

Kindly suggest any workarounds or answers for this.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to IP instead of the hostname?

Comment: Did you set up SSL when you installed WSUS? If so, you have to change ports on the connection screen.